# Time for the First Byte

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I got a web app deployed on Linux-Azure app service on a P1V2 server, location North US.
The time for the first byte is around 3/4 sec.

I have already:

- Set always on on the app service configuration
- Switch off the ARR Affinity
- Using HTTP 2.0

What else can be done to improve the TTFB ?

Comment: are there any dependency calls made by your web app, maybe a database or another API? If yes, where do these dependencies reside and do you happen to have the metrics on how long they are taking?  if you haven't already seen this link, please take a look - [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-performance-degradation]

Comment: Web app is in US (linux)
Database SQL Server in (North Europe)

Comment: cross region latency are usually in negligible milliseconds I would look at how long the DB operations are taking probably impacting the TTFB. You are already in a production grade App Service Plan and if your CPU and memory don't indicate any high usage it could be the database. Sorry, can't think of any setting on the infrastructure that can be tweaked to improve the TTFB